Unable to achieve real time playback in Blender even after baking
I have a hard time making Blender playback in real time. The project I'm working on is set to 25fps and includes a live action video set as a background image, an animated camera, and a simple animated object with a shape key, two lights and one shadow catcher. When I add a soft body to the object and bake it, it won't run at 25fps. Even after removing the soft body, it still doesn't. When I use Eevee, the playback remains around 10fps instead of 25fps. My setup: 3090, 11700K, and 32GB of RAM (Blender is using less than 6GB) and two SSDs. This is a general problem I have. I experimented with Houdini, and it seems easier to get real-time playback after baking/caching.

I can only repeat a comment which I have typed here very often: what people often do not understand is that the FPS do not necessarily mean you can play everything in realtime in your viewport, especially with complex scenes. It's a setting in the Output Properties. It is necessary if you render movie files because they need an FPS setting and it is used for playback of rendered image sequences. And it is needed for baking simulations so that Blender knows which playback speed is intended so that the physics are simulated in correct timing.

In good tutorials about animation you get taught that it is best to render a quick viewport animation (from the 3D Viewport menu View > Viewport Render Animation) to see if the timing looks correct when played at the correct FPS. These viewport animations render much quicker then "normal" renders and you are not even bound to the camera, you can render from any viewpoint you are currently looking at the scene to check your animation from different angles for example.

How many vertices are in this soft body, and the scene as a whole?

When you play the timeline inside blender, it still has to do a lot of calculation (drivers, morphs, textures, lighting, and so forth.)
Like @GordonBrinkman said, best to render a small, lightweight movie and play that back to check timing.
